# How to get ID of an element using Watir where the child contains the string i search for

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="minHeightBlock" style="min-height: 430px;">
<div class="borderbox"><div class="standaloneBox">
<div class="sysHeaderContainer clearfix"> … </div>
<div class="notesForGuests"> … </div>
<div class="filterBox clearfix"> … </div>
<div class="resListHeader"> … </div>
<div id="corporaContainer" class="fullList">
<div id="c-a06ffa6a-dc62-4640-9760-dbd661c7ffe8" class="resItem clearfix">
    <div class="resTitle">
    <span id="filter-empty" class="statBall statFile empty" title="Status: Empty corpus"></span>
    <span class="theText">
      12321 corpora
    </span>
</div>
    <div class="resType"> … </div>
    <div class="resSize"> … </div>
    <div class="resPermission private"> … </div>
    <div class="resDomain"> … </div>
    <div class="resDescr"> … </div>
    <div class="resDetails clearfix" style="display:none;"> … </div>
</div>
<div id="c-b8c0faba-e662-4998-836f-0ee58009b7fa" class="resItem clearfix"> … </div>
<div id="c-9d02b887-4835-4606-ad4b-775b39af9f48" class="resItem clearfix"> … </div>
<div id="c-021d3ba1-db03-4c4e-81a5-294737eb5b54" class="resItem clearfix"> … </div>
```

This is the code of the webpage im trying to script using Watir. All i know is only the what kind of span text the element should contain. I have many of these elements and i need to colect all of the element ID values so i can use them in further actions.

I have comented the places in the above code what i know and what i need to get.

So far i have tried this code:

```
    @b.div(:id, "pageHeader").link(:text, "Corpora").click
sleep 5 
@b.div(:id, "corporaContainer").spans(:text => /TestAuto\s.*/).each do |span|
    puts span.parent.attribute_value("id")
end
```

But no output is done. Maybe im doing something wrong. Help me get this nut shell cracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt was close. The problem is that `span.parent` only goes up to the `<div class="resTitle">`. You need to go up one more parent:

```
@b.div(:id, "corporaContainer").spans(:text => /corpora/).each do |span|
  puts span.parent.parent.attribute_value("id")
end
```

(Note that I changed the text in the locator of the `spans` since `TestAuto\s.*` did not match the sample html.)

Alternatively, I sometimes find it better to find the divs that contain the span. This way you do not have to worry about the number of parents changing:

```
p @b.divs(:class => 'resItem')
  .find_all { |div| div.span(:text => /corpora/).exists? }
  .collect { |div| div.id }
#=> ["c-a06ffa6a-dc62-4640-9760-dbd661c7ffe8"]
```

Below is a working example. Note that there are 2 important things:

- The list of results is loaded asynchronously. Therefore you need to wait for the list to finish loading before capturing the results. `sleep(5)` might work, but you are better off using an actual wait method (since it seems to take longer than 5 seconds).
- Make sure the search text actually exists on the page. In the below example, there is no "12321 corpora" title that was mentioned in the sample html.

Example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

# Title to search for:
title_text = /UniAdm/

# Go to the Corpora page:
@b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
@b.goto "https://www.letsmt.eu/Corpora.aspx"

# Wait for the results to load:
container = @b.div(:id, "corporaContainer")
container.div(:class => 'resItem').wait_until_present

# Find the matching ids:
p container.divs(:class => 'resItem')
  .find_all { |div| div.span(:class => 'theText', :text => title_text).exists? }
  .collect { |div| div.id }
#=> ["c-87ee80a9-e529-48b2-92be-bc8d76375478", "c-f139e781-4789-41f9-82e8-914e0e3eff81", "c-e17641d2-9364-4e87-9047-ba35580dc32f"]
```

Comment: The second variant isnt working. Gives me an output: Finding_Nemo.rb:17:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `browser' for main:Objec
t (NameError)

Myb its because i have defined:
@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-plugins --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-translate] ????

Comment: Sorry, yes. My local file for testing was using `browser`. I have updated the example.

Comment: But for the first variant and the second it doesnt give any output what so ever. Any idea why is that ? Myb the script is searching so long. Because i have almost 200 items to search thrue.

Comment: Does the second variant work correctly? If so, I would guess that the locator in the first variant is not right. If you do a `puts @b.div(:id, "corporaContainer").spans(:text => /corpora/).length` what do you get? My guess is that you are finding no spans, which means your page html is actually a bit different than the sample html in the question.

Comment: Well if i put the puts on length then i get 0. Thats means the script isnt finding any spans. I updated the sample with more information.

Comment: The SEcond variant is also giving no output.

Comment: There must be more to your problem. Both variants work for me against the sample html provided. Perhaps check out some of the other [common reasons that Watir fails to locate an element](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-unknownobjectexception---unable-to-locate-element).

Comment: I have tried this script one the test html and it also works. The webpage im trying to script is www.letsmt.eu -> corpora section. If i havent already boored you maybe you can check out.

Comment: I added a working example to show that the code does work. My guess is that the `sleep(5)` is not long enough, which is why it is often better to use a wait method.

Comment: I made a new question because to not spam this on. I hope you will help me with that also. Link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087601/how-can-i-store-div-id-element-value-in-array-for-usage-un-cycle